# Mongoose: Find all documents giving cast error

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

When using `Model.find()` or `Model.find({})`

I keep getting this error

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "all" at path "_id" for model "Customer"
```

What is causing this error?

Here is a bit more info

```
{
  messageFormat: undefined,
  stringValue: '"all"',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: 'all',
  path: '_id',
  reason: Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
  statusCode: 500,
  status: 'error',
  message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "all" at path "_id" for model "Customer"',
  name: 'CastError'
}
```

Comment: `all` isn't a valid value for an ObjectId.  The character `l` doesn't even fall within the valid 0-9, a-f characters that the hash can contain.  And ObjectId hashes are around 24 characters long

Comment: @Kody, Please share your query

Comment: There is no query, I leave it blank to find all the documents. @PulkitAggarwal

Comment: @KodyV Can you share some documents from your data? Its seems that something is wrong with your data.

Answer (score 0):

This is a long time question, but hope my answer helpful in future.
There is no problem in this code, but in router:

```js
router.get('/:id', find);
router.get('/all', findAll);
```

This cause router always use `/:id` route first, instead of `/all`, so mongoose try to cast `all` to `id` and cause that error message.

Just reverse these line, the problem will gone:

```js
router.get('/all', findAll);
router.get('/:id', find);
```